# How to handle 'missing' or 'wrong file names' urls when using OWIN Static Files?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, owin, static-files

I've successfully used Static Files in my asp.net web api project. It is serving files that exist perfectly.
The problem is when the file no longer exists (got deleted) or it is renamed or misspelled, requesting the url causes Startup.cs to be called (again) and somehow this is throwing exceptions.

```
<handlers>
  ...
  <remove name="StaticFile" />
  <add name="Owin" verb="" path="/media" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on the exceptions - what exceptions  are being thrown ?

Comment: Yes, the "Startup.Configuration" method is called (again) ... which is throwing exceptions in my Dependency Injected components. Perhaps due to duplicate containers or so .. 
Please try to regenerate it ... it is straight forward. The exceptions are not an issue. My Concern is when a wrong file is called, the startup configuration is called again and again (as if it rebooting)

Comment: For me, OWIN initialization is called exactly once for matching resources and exactly once for non matching. Why don't to try to properly handle you container initialization and you could be good to go?

Comment: @Kalitsov any reason why OWIN initializes twice ?
I think this is very strange, cause "Startup" means start once to me ;).
If that was the behavior by design, than I think I should be doing something to avoid exceptions from the container ...

Comment: @JalalEl-Shaer - I'm not able to reproduce. I can see the Startup is called twice - once on application start, once for first hit to "/media" path - but that's entirely different from issue you're describing.

Comment: @JalalEl-Shaer Could you create more complete example and upload it somewhere? Мy setup is the bare minimum.

Comment: Yes sure ... I'll prepare something and share it